# Apache Htaccess redirect and change querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Say that i have this url structures

```
http://sub1.mydomain.com/?parameter_1=a1&parameter_2=b1
http://sub2.mydomain.com/?parameter_1=a2&parameter_2=b2
http://sub3.mydomain.com/?parameter_1=a3&parameter_2=b3
```

And I need to rewrite the urls with the following rules
1. domain will stay the same
2. parameter_1 will stay the same
3. parameter_2 will change by a manual list
4. need to use single condition for each change on parameter_2

thougt about something like that but i really dont see it working

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter_2=b1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{QUERY_STRING}&parameter_2=b2 [R=301,L]
```

For example

```
old url http://sub1.mydomain.com/?parameter_1=a1&parameter_2=b1

new url http://sub1.mydomain.com/?parameter_1=a1&parameter_2=c1
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule is little bit complicated but it can be done.

Use this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?parameter_2=b1(&.+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1parameter_2=c1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```